# Can't able to edit my input field less than he mainRate

Tags: javascript, reactjs, logic

In this input I can't able to edit below the mainRate when the staydays is greater than 1. Ex. if my mainRate is 990 and the Total ADvance came as 2990 and when I edit this total advance I can't able to edit it less than 990(mainRate). I guess there might be a problem with my logic.

```js
  <p>Total Advance</p>
  <input
    style={{ width: "4rem" }}
    type="text"
    value={
      Number(staydays) > 1
        ? roomno.length * mainAvanceRate +
          roomno.length * Number(mainRate) * Number(staydays - 1)
        : roomno.length * mainAvanceRate
    }
    name="mainAvanceRate"
    onChange={(e) => setmainAvanceRate(e.target.value / Number(roomno.length))}
  />;
```

I want to edit the input box. When the stay days is 1 then it gets edited but when the input is greater than 1 it doesn't get below the mainRat.

Answer (score 0):

React offers 2 approaches to access the value of an input field: using  controlled or uncontrolled inputs techniques.

The controlled input should look like this.

```
const [value, setValue] = useState('');
<input
  value={value}
  name="mainAvanceRate"
  onChange={(e) => setValue(e.target.value)}
/>
```

Otherwise, the value entered by the user and the displayed value may differ, causing confusion.

In your case, you are using controlled input, but the logic and data input are mixed.

You should separate the logic and data input.

- You can use input validation to handle the logic.
- If it is not posssible, you may need to use 2 inputs for mainAvanceRate and totalAdvance.